# Interface with dynamic and static properties

Tags: typescript

I've got a question regarding a more dynamic kind of interface where dynamic and static properties can be used together - even if they are of different types. Is this possible? If yes, does it make any sense at all?

Let's say I want something like this.

```
type MyCustomType = {
    foo: string;
};

export interface MyInterface {
    [key: string]: MyCustomType;
    bar: string;
};
```

I want to make sure that a certain prop (that I do not know the name of in advance) points to a value of type `MyCustomType`. The rest of the properties in `MyInterface` I do know the names of and they point to other types.

The above code results in the following error:

```
Property 'bar' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type MyCustomType.
```

I could get around that by using either intersection *(as the below example)* or `any`  however.. that will also affect my dynamic prop and ruin guarantees of it's type.

```
export interface MyInterface {
    [key: string]: MyCustomType | string;
    bar: string;
};
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated :)

Comment: It definitely makes sense and is doable in TypeScript, see my answer

Comment: Look into [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) in Typescript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done in the following way, using an intersection:

```
type MyCustomType = {
    foo: string;
};

type MyInterface = {
    [key: string]: MyCustomType;
} & { bar: string };
```

In order for intersections to work MyInterface has to be a type.

Comment: How does this not answer the question @JaredSmith? This very much answers the question, I think you did not understand the question seeing your comment on the original post ;)

Comment: @AliNasserzadeh Awesome! Thank you :) Not that it matters, but could you clarify; does `MyInterface` has to be a `type` instead of an `interface` as in your example to work? If you clarify that in your post, I will not only mark it as the correct answer but also upvote it :)

Comment: @entiendoNull no problem :) yes it has to be a type for intersections to work