# How to use a type with static and dynamic typed properties

Tags: typescript, dynamic-properties

I am trying to use a type that has all the properties of one type, but also allows adding dynamic properties of another type (similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60954483/interface-with-dynamic-and-static-properties)).

Types are defined like this:

```
type Foo = string | string[]
type Bar = { n: number, str?: string }

// A dictionary which only allows Foo values
type FooDict = { [key: string]: Foo | undefined }

// Has all static properties of Bar plus some dynamic Foo properties
type FooBar = FooDict & Bar
```

and I am expecting to use them like this:

```
const bar: Bar = { n: 1 }
const fooBar: FooBar = bar
const n: number = fooBar.n
const str: string | undefined = fooBar.str
const foo: Foo | undefined = fooBar['someRandomKey']
```

Problem is that the second line gives a compile error: *"Type 'Bar' is not assignable to type 'FooBar'. Type 'Bar' is not assignable to type 'FooDict'. Property 'n' is incompatible with index signature. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Foo | undefined'.  TS2322"*.

I don't see any reason why it couldn't work.

- All the keys of `Bar` and `FooDict` are strings, so there is no mismatch.
- If using a key of `Bar`, we can use the corresponding static property of Bar.
- Otherwise, we can use the type from `FooDict`, which is either `Foo` (when the property exists) or `undefined` (when using a key with no value).

As mentioned in the linked question, this works if the dynamic properties are typed as `any`. But since I only need to set Foo instances into the dynamic properties, I would like to enforce it with the type system. Is this possible?

Comment: please share reproducible example. `getBar` is not defined

Comment: It's not really relevant, since any Bar instance will do. Nevertheless, I updated the question as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that `FooBar` and `Bar` are not compatible since `FooBar` promises a string based index signature while `Bar` does not. (Basically that is what the error message says)

```
const fooBar: FooBar = {...}
const bar: Bar = fooBar;

// this will work since foobar has a string index signature
fooBar['someRandomKey'] // undefined | Foo

// this will give a compilation error since there is no string based index signature
bar['someRandomKey'] // NOTE: it will work at runtime though (which is why it is so confusing)
```

If you want to assing `Bar` to `Foobar` you have to provide a respective signature which will basically equal your `FooBar` type.
Assigning `FooBar` to `Bar` should be always possible